# Toast message not displaying in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am a beginner trying to follow a basic tutorial, I created an empty activity layout for my app and was trying to display a toast message like this:

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are inside the `Activity`, the `context` can be the `Activity` itself, so replace:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

With:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked when I tried installing another virtual device